# Is there an alternative for lookbehind in this case?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that is not working on Safari because it contains lookbehind which is not supported:

```
\b((a[a-c])[^\"]*(?<![0-9])2(?![0-9])[^\"]*)
```

is there any alternative that does EXACTLY what the regex above does? (the character right before the 2 must NOT be a digit so this will pass aa4a2 but not this aa4a22

Thanks.

Comment: For the string `'$&ab$222&a2b222'` your regex matches `'ab$222&a2b222'`. That match is captured in group 1 (why capture a match?), and `'ab'` is captured in group 2. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KIGow2/1). Is that your intent? It's helpful to readers to begin a question by stating, in words, what you attempting to do, possibly adding one or more examples for illustration (including the desired result for each), then present your code, explain its shortcomings and state your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b((a[a-c])(?:[^\"]*[^\"0-9])?2(?![0-9])[^\"]*)
```

The `(?:[^\"]*[^\"0-9])?` part is a non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `"` and then any one char that is not a `"` and a digit.

Note that the consuming character of the added group is fine here since the `[^\"]*` pattern was able to match an empty string, hence the use of the optional non-capturing group.